# Fatal error Upgrading to 1.9.1 related to ConfigurableSwatches

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, fatal-error

After installing 1.9.1 via Magento Connect (I know not the method of choice), I'm running into an issue when I turn Compilation back on I get this error on both Frontend and Admin side:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data' not found in /home/devcirc/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

I went to System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches to try and disable Swatched, but I get:
404 Error
Page not found.

I can seem to figure out what's missing from the Admin or how to disable the swatches? Any ideas?

Edit to Add System.log Errors:

> 2015-05-09T00:52:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/devcirc/public_html/includes/src/Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/devcirc/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
>   2015-05-09T00:52:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/devcirc/public_html/includes/src/Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/devcirc/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/devcirc/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: is this error there only when you turn on compilation?

Comment: See edit to post includting system.log errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer...looks like it took flushing all caches, logging out of admin, and then re-running compilation. I found the answer here:

[*Solved* Warning: include(/public_html/includes/src/addon.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/solved-warning-include-public-html-includes-src-addon-php-function-include)

Answer (score 0):

May be you cant login your admin panel am i right??
First go to the app/etc/modules and goto mage_configurableswatches.xml file open and where thereis one option acrive true rename active false than flush cache from var/cache now you can login in to admin panle now rename again to true and  go to the system>tools>comilation>run compilation again now no error.